# CakePHP 3.x - Block clicking active page in Pagination

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-3.x

How can I block the possibility of clicking a current (selected) page from the list of the available pages displayed with the following function:

```
$this->Paginator->numbers();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so by change the corresponding template to not generate a link. The default template for the `current` page number looks like:

```
<li class="active"><a href="">{{text}}</a></li>
```

So you could for example do something along the lines of:

```
$this->Paginator->templates([
    'current' => '<li class="active">{{text}}</li>'
]);

// ...

echo $this->Paginator->numbers();
```

or whatever suits you.

See also

- **[Cookbook > View > Helpers > Paginator > Loading Templates from a File](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/paginator.html#loading-templates-from-a-file)**
- **[Cookbook > View > Helpers > Paginator > Changing Templates at Run-time](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/paginator.html#changing-templates-at-run-time)**

Comment: Thank you, this is of course is the answer. The initial problem I had was Interner Explorer - I do not know why that browser does not provide a correct link for a current page in Paginator (Firefox does that). Now, I understand that it is enough to change the template to: '<li class="active"><a href="{{url}}">{{text}}</a></li>'